# How to insert layer to PostgreSQL from QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I need to insert the data of a layer of the qgis project into an existing table of postgis I have been using this code to test, but it gives an error since the method used creates the table in postgresql does not insert the elements if the layer exists.

```
def test_insertar_en_Postgis(self):
    app = QgsApplication.instance()
    self.conf = QgsSettings(
        app.qgisSettingsDirPath() + "QGIS/gestion_proyectos.ini", QSettings.IniFormat
    )

    self.conf.beginGroup("/conexion")
    self.servidor = self.conf.value("servidor")
    self.puerto = self.conf.value("puerto")
    self.conf.endGroup()
    self.conf.beginGroup("/cfg_nomenclatura")
    self.nomenclatura = self.conf.value("nomenclatura")
    self.directorio = self.conf.value("directoriogpk")

    self.usuario = self.cfgdlg.v_usuario.text()
    self.contrasena = self.cfgdlg.v_contrasena.text()

    layers = self.iface.mapCanvas().layers()
    indice =0;
    for layer in layers:
        indice= indice + 1
        con_string = "dbname='bdsapromat' host='" + self.servidor + "' port='" + self.puerto + "' user='" + self.usuario + "' password='" + self.contrasena + "' key=geo_id type= GEOMETRY  table= \"25_areas_verdes_terrenos\".test"+str(indice)+" (geom)"

        err = QgsVectorLayerExporter.exportLayer(layer, con_string, 'postgres',QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('4326'),True)

        if err != 0:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Hay error al insertar en postgis ', "Proyecto", level=Qgis.Info)
```

Answer (score 4):

I have solved the problem I had to add elements to an existing postgis table from qgis using pyqgis, for this I have used the plugin developed by Germán Carrillo Append features to layer, calling it from pyqgis as a Processing algorithm.
I enter the new code

```
def insertar_en_Postgis(self):
    app = QgsApplication.instance()
    self.conf = QgsSettings(
        app.qgisSettingsDirPath() + "QGIS/gestion_proyectos.ini", QSettings.IniFormat
    )

    self.conf.beginGroup("/conexion")
    self.servidor = self.conf.value("servidor")
    self.puerto = self.conf.value("puerto")
    self.conf.endGroup()
    self.conf.beginGroup("/cfg_nomenclatura")
    self.nomenclatura = self.conf.value("nomenclatura")
    self.directorio = self.conf.value("directoriogpk")

    self.usuario = self.cfgdlg.v_usuario.text()
    self.contrasena = self.cfgdlg.v_contrasena.text()
    uritarget = QgsDataSourceUri()
    uritarget.setConnection(self.servidor, str(self.puerto), "bdsapromat", self.usuario, self.contrasena,
                            QgsDataSourceUri.SslDisable)
    uritarget.setSrid('4326')

    alllayers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()

    for layerorigen in alllayers:
        uritarget.setDataSource('public', layerorigen.name(), "geom", '')
        self.target = QgsVectorLayer(uritarget.uri(), layerorigen.name(), "postgres")
        processing.run("etl_load:appendfeaturestolayer", {
        'SOURCE_LAYER': layerorigen,
        'SOURCE_FIELD': 'geo_id',
        'TARGET_LAYER': self.target,
        'TARGET_FIELD': 'geo_id',
        'ACTION_ON_DUPLICATE': 2})
```